# Dictionary lookup wider and taller (pop-up dictionary lookup styling) in OS X

Tags: macos, dictionary

It's possible to change the font and the font-size for 3-finger lookup popup. You just need to edit css file for dictionaries you use, e.g.:

```
sudo vim /Library/Dictionaries/New\ Oxford\ American\ Dictionary.dictionary/Contents/Resources/DefaultStyle.css
```

find `html.apple_client-panel body {` and edit properties

Now I actually want to go further and make the entire popup area bigger - little wider and little taller. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **find out dictionary path you want to modify**. This is dependent on the dictionary you want to modify, but you path should look something like this:

```
/System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServi‌​ces_dictionaryOSX/04‌​2bf65b3ae80e4564c339‌​fcf00fa9924bd16dd3.a‌​sset/AssetData/Apple Dictionary.dictionary/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Apple‌​Dictionary.css
```

Then open this file in any text/code editor you'd like, it could be even `vim`, like in the original question, and open it for modification, search for `font-size` parameter for `body` element, it could be defined in `pt`, `px`, `em`. If you want to deep into CSS details, you may read up tutorials or manual on the [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). **It appears to be regular CSS file**, for definition of styles, so it's easy to work with it.

You may change the font-size, to make it bigger/smaller, it could achieved by modification of parameters in `CSS`:

```
body {
  ...
  font-size: 15pt; /* <== look for this parameter, and scale it up to your taste */
  ...
}
```

Or like this:

```
html.apple_client-panel body {
    ...
    font-size: 15px;
    ...
}
```

You may find some screenshots and additional explanation on [apple.disscussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3736067?tstart=0).

One also can play with `line-height`, if `font-size` haven't brought enough readability. If you want to change the window itself or spacing around text, then you may want to modify [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) (`margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, etc) or [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) (`padding-left`, `padding-right`, etc).

Tried to explain this to the guys, who are not web-developers themselves, hope this helps. Ask if you gotten additional questions to me, or search them on StackOverflow (it's for developers questions), but I think it will be straight-forward for you now.

Comment: This method no longer works. The css file is locked and I can't modify it. Are there any other options?