# Increase font size in pop up dictionary window in OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, font, dictionary

On my Macbook Air running Sierra 10.12.5, there is no longer a Dictionaries directory under /Library, so the below suggested fix no longer seems to apply:
[Dictionary lookup wider and taller (pop-up dictionary lookup styling) in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163652/dictionary-lookup-wider-and-taller-pop-up-dictionary-lookup-styling-in-os-x)

Is there still a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> In macOS High Sierra the location of the files has changed. And maybe also the structure too. The files are now under:
>
> ```
> /System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServi‌​ces_dictionaryOSX/
> ```

The directory structure has changed in more recent versions of OS X but the same approach linked to above works.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, the answer should contain all the details necessary. It would be useful to include a link to the other forum you got the information from.