# How to edit locked css files on Mac?

Tags: mac, dictionary, css

I'm trying to change the font size of the popup dictionary by following instructions in this link: [Dictionary lookup wider and taller (pop-up dictionary lookup styling) in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163652/dictionary-lookup-wider-and-taller-pop-up-dictionary-lookup-styling-in-os-x)

I need to edit AppleDictionary.css file using TextEdit. However, I am unable to do so as the file is locked. I tried unchecking the "Locked" box to unlock the file but it says I don't have permission to unlock the file.

I need to edit the line

> font-size: 12pt;

so that the text size in my popup dictioinary becomes bigger. How can I do so?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those file(s) are in subdirectories of  `/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX`

This location is part of the sealed system volume, you cannot alter files here.

Comment: That sucks. Is there any other way to increase text size for the popup dictionary on mac?

Comment: @TaeNyFan If there was a way, I think it would be in `Settings > Accessibility`. But I checked and couldn't find a setting for that (in Sonoma 14.2.1). I agree it sucks, and would recommend sending constructive feedback to Apple about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is on a special filesystem called SSV(sealed system volume). Although `statfs` tells you that it is mounted from the same place as your home...

You may try to edit it in Recovery after disabling it with `csrutil(8)`, then `bless(8)` it again. eclecticlight.co has written a good [article](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/) on this.